# Jenkins is returning 302 to bitbucker webhook

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I am trying to create a CI with my application, so every time that the master branch receive a commit I want to run a job. But after configured the webhook in bitbucket to `http://my-host:8080/bitbucket-hook/` it's returning status 302.

[image]

Comment: Are the two blacked-out parts identical?

Comment: Yes.. they are.

Comment: Just checking. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

302 is a redirect code - Jenkins is sending you from `http://server:8080/bitbucket-hook` (without trailing slash) to `http://server:8080/bitbucket-hook/` (with trailing slash).

If you add the trailing slash to the webhook URL in Bitbucket, then do you get a different status code?

Comment: Why does the trailing slash(`/`) make the difference? Could you explain more?

Comment: That's a question for Jenkins to answer - but if it consistenly redirects you to the version with the trailing slash, then go to the version with the trailing slash.

Comment: It happens with GItHub aswell, adding / at the end resolved.

Comment: It doesn't matter who's sending the webhook - Jenkins is sending the redirect. So it'll happen with Bitbucket, GitHub, GitLab, or anything else.